# Gnus required an updated Google password and now will not send messages

Tags: gnus

emacs 25 on linux Debian;

On a running computer which had been largely ignored for a couple of years,
I loaded gnus and was prompted for my google password.  I updated my google
password, entered it, but gnus would not send mail. Same with the gnus on
my main desktop.

on main desktop
:~$ less .authinfo
machine smtp.gmail.com login imputerate@gmail.com
password "ictcysxurcxqzjol" port 587

no "authinfo" mentioned in .emacs

BUT in .gnus.el

(setq user-mail-address "imputerate@gmail.com")
(setq user-full-name "peter hodgson")
(load-library "smtpmail")
(load-library "starttls")

(setq gnutls-min-prime-bits 2048)  ;;recent glitch reduced them to 256)
(setq smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it

```
  smtpmail-stream-type  'starttls
  message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
  smtpmail-smtp-service 587
  smtpmail-auth-credentials "~/.authinfo")
```

---

error messages when i try to send an email-

"250 SMTPUTF8
AUTH PLAIN 
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not
accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials e8sm365299oti.76 - gsmtp
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection e8sm365299oti.76 - gsmtp
Process smtpmail connection broken by remote peer"

Comment: Please format your code, using a line with three backquotes before and after it.

Comment: do the lines from a dot file count as "code"?

Comment: Any code is more readable here when formatted. If you don't care then neither do I.